# Could you please explain the meaning of "retaining wall relation"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

"there is a retaining-wall relation between language and group.
"

I looked up the retaining wall (Retaining walls are relatively rigid walls used for supporting soil laterally so that it can be retained at different levels on the two sides. Retaining walls are structures designed to restrain soil to a slope that it would not naturally keep to (typically a steep, near-vertical, or vertical slope.)

However, I found it hard for me to understand what kind of relation is retaining wall relations?

Comment: So not having seen the reference (and no context being given) one can suppose that something is being kept behind the wall and the other is the wall.  It seems more plausible that the use of language keeps a group together and segregated from other groups.

Comment: @Jim I think you've got it there. That hadn't occurred to me, I was thinking more of logical or mathematical groups and getting nowhere, but the idea of a language (or even a dialect) holding a shared group together seems quite reasonable. As you say a bit more context would help a lot.

Comment: A retaining wall is supportive, so the relationship is that one supports the other. The rest is guesswork, for the language could support the group by keeping it together... and apart from others who don't speak that language.

Answer (score 4):

This question is about an analogy.

Soil on a slope has a natural tendency to disperse downhill and is prevented from doing so by the boundary of a retaining wall.

Languages have a natural tendency to disperse by intermarriage, cultural exchange, conquest, trade and migration. They may be prevented from doing so by geographical boundaries such as rivers, deserts, mountain ranges and oceans).

More relevant to this question are the boundaries to the dispersion of languages imposed by human groups. Nation states, ethnic groups, tribes, religious groups and others may create boundaries to the dispersion of languages either by rigidly policed physical frontiers or by ingrained human (ethnic, religious, tribal) attitudes.

Whatever their nature, these human boundaries between groups inhibit the natural dispersal of language, in a way that is analogous to the inhibition of natural downslope soil movement by retaining walls.

Answer (score 1):

I think this figurative idea has to be construed faithfully on the model of the literal meaning. In this meaning an element, earth, has a natural propensity to occupy as much space as is available, to spread to as much territory as there is in its proximity and thus to lose its initial spatial distribution, its shape. It is the wall that prevents that from happening. In the figurative meaning,  particularising the analogy on the getting out of shape level, language (more or less loose earth), is  found to be a mass with the tendency to lose its function, to be eroded by various agents and the group action to prevent that is that of a propping up by a sheer forcing into "shape". Here the action of the group and the group are identified so that the group is the wall.

However, from what a comment suggests to me  ([user Jim](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/550834/could-you-please-explain-the-meaning-of-retaining-wall-relation/550837#comment1355906_550834)) the same relation in the other way is quite an appealing possibility. Possibly, both relations have been meant.

Answer (score 0):

From [Course Hero](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p1q67ug4/or-to-reject-Europe-Yo-12-and-cling-together-in-their-dialect-making-themselves/),

> As I said at the start, there is a retaining-wall relation between language and group. To speak a language is to take on a world, a culture.

The author continues,

> The Antilles Negro who wants to be white will be the whiter as he gains greater mastery of the cultural tool that language is. [In this case, the French language.]

So there is no mystery here. Read the entire article for more explanation. You can find it by entering "there is a retaining-wall relation between language and group" in a Google search (including quotation marks).

Comment: Please note that I have down-voted your question (and up-voted the two answers offered by Anton and LPH). I also recommend that you take the "Tour" by clicking on the "?" in the upper right-hand corner of the screen to get a better idea of how to use ES&U. Thank you.